# if within if python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

I have been searching but cannot find information to help me correct this.

To practice programming in python I am working on control code for home automation.  I started out with temperature conversion calculator and that works well.  Then I put that within another "if" to give it the functionality to change temperature and read current temperature.  This put my convertor "if" as a sub to my control "if".  The program opens well, but only goes to the line for the converter.  It is not going to the "elif" statements that are a part of the general control.  Below:

```
while True:

    task = (raw_input("What would you like to do? "))

    if task == 'Convert' or 'convert':
        ask = raw_input("C to get Celsius, F to get Fahrenheit: ")

        if ask == 'F':
            Cconvert = float(raw_input("Temp in C: "))
            F = Cconvert * 9 / 5 + 32
            print F, 'F'

        elif ask == 'C':
            Fconvert = float(raw_input("Temp in F: "))
            C = ((Fconvert - 32) * 5) / 9
            print C, 'C'

        else:
            print "That is not a temperature measurement I understand."

    elif task == "ChangeTemp":
        temptype = raw_input("Celsius or Fahrenheit? ")
        if temptype == "Celcius" or "celsius":
            temp = float(raw_input("New Temp: ")), str(temptype)
        elif temptype == "Fahrenheit" or "fahrenheit":
            temp = float(raw_input("New Temp: ")), str(temptype)
        else:
            print "That is not a temperature measurement I understand."

    elif task == "SetTemp":
        print temp

    else:
        print "I do not know what you are asking."
```

If this is answered elsewhere and I simply could not find it, please link.

Comment: What is your input that you tried? Make sure to match the CaSes

Comment: @baloo, I had matched them case-by-case, but as was explained to me, my if statement for "Convert" was treating "convert" as an always True test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if task == 'Convert' or 'convert':
```

That line will always succeed since it is equivalent to

```
if (task == 'Convert') or ('convert'):
```

`'convert'` taken as a boolean expression on its own will result in `True`. The correct way to write it is like this:

```
if task == 'Convert' or task == 'convert':
```

You could also do one of these:

```
if task in ('Convert', 'convert'):

if task.lower() == 'convert':
```

Comment: I would go for the .lower when setting task variable so that cases are no problems in either test

Comment: Thank you. The explanation helps a lot, actually.  I didn't even think about the fact that it is reading them as separate Booleans.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want:

```
if task == 'Convert' or 'convert':
```

Even if `task` is not `Convert`, the `convert` is true value always. So you will never get to the `elif` part.

You have to do this:

```
if task == 'Convert' or task == 'convert':
```

(ignoring better ways to do the same, considering the context)

Comment: Thanks.  I know there are better, but this code was to practice what I've already learned so that I can understand it better.  The line-by-line explanations are helping A LOT and I don't think I'll make that mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in this line of code:

```
if task == 'Convert' or 'convert':
```

Replace it with this line of code:

```
if task == 'Convert' or task == 'convert':
```

Or better, use the [lower()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) method of str:

```
if task.lower() == 'convert'
```

Comment: Thank you.  The responses have been a great help.